# adding the data-i18n attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a form which is supporting multiple languages by using data-i18n, and I want to use jquery to add the message below the form if the input of the form cannot be validated.

(The multi-language message content of all sites is included in the local json files: the form page is named as formPage and the input section is named as inputDescription)

But the message content doesn't show up  although I'm using $(jquery).attr(), can anyone help to check if I do anything wrong or what should I do to make it works?

Thanks in advance!

```js
$(".msg").attr("data-i18n", "formPage.inputDescription" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="number" step=any class="form-control" min="5000" max="1000000" value="">
<small data-i18n="" class="form-text msg"></small>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it's working fine. The string "formPage.inputDescription" is siccessfully getting added to the `data-i18n` attribute of the `small` tag. Which library are you using for the multi-language messages?

Comment: At what point of the flow does the library read the attributes? If it reads them on page load, you need to ensure you add them first.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thank you for your reply, I use this $(jquery).attr() in a $(jquery).click() function for the button at the end of the form. The Chrome inspect shows the attribution has been added but the content still not showing up.

Comment: @Shishir Thank you for your reply, I'm using the jquery 3.3.1 and jquery-i18next, in my chrome inspect although I can see the string "formPage.inputDescription" has been added to the small tag, but the content of the string is still not showing up below the form when the form doesn't pass the validation. And this data-i18n multi-languages attribution works well if it has been originally put in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer, post and share here. It's necessary to call localize `$(jquery).localize()` again after the attribution `$(jquery).attr()`, although localize has been called in the html file.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. But this was my first question and I never really got feedback ;-)